# C++ crash when use setmode with _O_U8TEXT to deal with unicode

Tags: c++, windows, utf-8, crash, visual-studio-2017

What I've tried to print unicode is

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT);
string str = u8"unicode 한글 hangul";
cout << str << endl;
```

I used setmode to show and get unicode correctly, but It crashed with [Debug Assertion Fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpdjN.png).

However,

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
wstring str = L"unicode 한글 hangul";
wcout << str << endl;
```

_O_U16TEXT compile and print correctly.

What should I do to use UTF-8? Do I have to find another trick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[_setmode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode) mentions `_O_U8TEXT` and `_O_U16TEXT` (finally), but doesn't go into detail what they do. It does state that these are **translation modes**.

The documentation for [_wsopen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sopen-wsopen) lists (emphasis mine):

`_O_U16TEXT`
Opens a **file** in Unicode UTF-16 mode.
`_O_U8TEXT`
Opens a **file** in Unicode UTF-8 mode.

What this means is: when using the unicode io facilities (`wprintf`, `std::wcout`, etc.), which means using unicode (UTF-16) strings, the output will be translated to either UTF-16 or UTF-8 when they're written to the file.

Try this:

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT);
std::wcout << L"unicode 한글 hangul\n";
```

You shouldn't see a difference on a console, but if you redirect the output:

```
> u8out | hexdump -C
00000000  75 6e 69 63 6f 64 65 20  ed 95 9c ea b8 80 20 68  |unicode ...... h|
00000010  61 6e 67 75 6c 0d 0a                              |angul..|
00000017

> u16out | hexdump -C
00000000  75 00 6e 00 69 00 63 00  6f 00 64 00 65 00 20 00  |u.n.i.c.o.d.e. .|
00000010  5c d5 00 ae 20 00 68 00  61 00 6e 00 67 00 75 00  |\... .h.a.n.g.u.|
00000020  6c 00 0d 00 0a 00                                 |l.....|
00000026
```

In theory this should mean that you can also use `_O_U8TEXT` on `stdin` to read UTF-8 input, but in practice that doesn't always work:

```
> u8in < u8.txt
unicode 한글 hangul €µöäüß

> u8in
unicode 한글 hangul €µöäüß
unicode ?? hangul ?攄��
```

`_O_U16TEXT` *appears* to work with console input (on my machine), but then you can't use UTF-8 encoded redirected input/output:

```
> u16in
unicode 한글 hangul €µöäüß
unicode 한글 hangul €µöäüß
```

You can read more about this here: [Conventional wisdom is retarded, aka What the @#%&* is _O_U16TEXT?](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2008/03/18/8306597.html)

PS: What the assertion is telling you is that you **can't** use unicode output with the ANSI output facilities. Curiously, that is not enforced if you don't set one of the unicode modes, though...

Comment: Thanks for clarification. So the problem is in windows console, not a setmode. right?

Comment: @user: No. The issue is that you are using facilities in a way they weren't meant to be used.

Comment: @IInspectable: What they were meant to be? I expected their UTF translation on the file. So I thought I can use it in windows console,  because standard input and output are processed through file system.

Comment: If you want to use the Unicode translation modes, you must use wide strings.

Comment: @user: `_setmode` controls, how input is translated to output. Setting `stdout` to `_O_U8TEXT` doesn't magically allow you to **pass** UTF-8 strings. It's just that the **output** is UTF-8. The input is implied by the API (ANSI in case of `std::cout`).